# Newbie question: why does vscode in python output extra line breaks between print statements in the debug console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Running vscode 1.33.1, default configuration with python extension.

Using basic print statements, e.g.:

```
print("hello world1")
print("hello world2")
```

I'd expect the following output to the debug console:

```
hello world1
hello world2
```

instead, I get:

```
hello world1

hello world2
```

seems to throw in extra line breaks everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is faced by VScode users after updating to version 1.33. The issue here is that the python extension sends extra newline output events. This is a bug and has already been raised as an issue in [git](https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/1327)

Comment: Thanks very much! Looks like it should be fixed in the next release

Comment: @AESL Hope so.  Please mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the tick mark) if it clarifies your query. It will help other users also to understand that answer is verified. :)